# The How to format sidebar slides down when scrolling

Tags: bug, design

I just noticed this today while I was framing a question. The "How to Format" help section appears to slide down screen. Please see the screenshots to see this

[image]

[image]

I don't know if this has already been filed or reported and if this is expected - since I don't know a lot of HTML/CSS. This looks like something that shouldn't happen (purely my personal opinion).
I am on a Mac (OS Sierra), and was working on the Chrome browser ( 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit))